# Auto adjust image in div as per the size

Tags: html, css

I want to show image in an div of constant height and width. All I want is to auto adjust the image in an div, if its an vertical image it should be centre aligned leaving black space on left and right, if its an horizonal image it should leave black space on top and bottom and if its 1:1 it should take complete space inside the div.
Please help me with the css of div and image tag.

```
<div>
<img src="image.png">
</div>
```

Comment: img {
object-fit: contain; // or cover, I don't remember
}

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Add, style=" width:100%;"

Comment: object-fit: contain; working fine.
Thanks :)